# Introduce missingness into mixed data using MAR, MNAR and MCAR in Python

Tags: python, keras, missing-data, imputation

I am trying to introduce missing values into a complete dataset(adult dataset) using MAR, MNAR and MCAR mechanisms. Including missing values such as using `df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .2)`   can be included. But I am unable to do it using **MAR, MNAR and MCAR** mechanisms.

Comment: Can you show us the code with which you've tried it? Perhaps there's an easy fix but we can't know without seeing your code

Comment: I use this one (https://rmisstastic.netlify.app/how-to/python/generate_html/how%20to%20generate%20missing%20values) but it only for numerical data, this one is in  R [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528719/simulate-data-and-randomly-add-missing-values-to-dataframe/50543195#50543195] .

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: How to include missingness in a dataset. For example, I have Iris dataset, I want to include missing values in the dataset using missing at random mechanism.